# content search web part (slide show) with black background

Tags: content-search-web-part, formatting, cswp

I have been trying to find the correct code inside the standard template to modify the content search web part (slide show) background color from black to something else.

[image]

I do not find anything in the slide show HTML template to allow me to change it. Also by selecting the container with F12 I do not grasp the whole container.

Anyone know how to do it?

Comment: can you post a screenshot?

Comment: edited and added a photo

Comment: You can search in DOM about the background color, You should find class with that CSS and override the class with your respected background color.

Comment: as written in the original post, I have tried in dom and there is no way it allows me to select the whole box

Answer (score 1):

As the items slide, the selection would be undone so you need select the parent container. Here's the CSS

```
div.cbs-Slideshow {
  background-color: #3079ab;
}
```